# Register with Autofac class that directly implements the open generic interface type

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, autofac

I have an Interface:

```
public interface IFileParserService<ITxtFile>
{
    void Parse(IEnumerable<ITxtFile> rows);
}
```

I have an different implementations of this interface as

```
public class ProductParserService : IFileParserService<TxtFileProduct>
{
    //implementation
}
public class CategoryParserService : IFileParserService<TxtFileCategory>
{
    //implementation
}
```

Models are:

```
public class TxtFileProduct : ITxtFile
{
}
```

and

```
public class TxtFileCategory : ITxtFile
{
}
```

What is a way to register these types with Autofac?
Thank you.

Comment: @NightOwl888 thanks for your comment. The answer at your link doesn't work for me. When I'm trying to use builder.RegisterGeneric it throws exception: "The type ProductParserService is not an open generic type definition". What I've tried exactly is: builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(ProductParserService)).As(typeof(IFileParserService<>))

Comment: To prevent confusion, you should rename `IFileParserService<ITxtFile>` to `IFileParserService<TTxtFile>`, because the generic type argument is _not related_ to your `ITxtFile` interface. If you want them to be, you should change your interface to the following: `IFileParserService<TTxtFile> where TTxtFile : ITxtFile`.